# How many processors can I remove from the VMs?

Tags: 18.04, cpu

I need to reduce the amount of CPU on some VM because of the limitations of the virtual data center.
How can I exactly find out how many CPUs I can reduce? I've given screenshots where you can see CPU utilization. Let's imagine this is + - constantly load of this VM.
Is load average 8.00 is high for my VM?
If I see 120% of CPU load, does it mean that I need only 2 cores and will be enough for this installation?
[htop screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kskRh.png)

[cat /proc/cpuinfo screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UoIg.png)

Comment: What problems, if any, are you trying to solve?

Comment: @ChanganAuto now I need to find out is this VM load very high or not. If load is high, can I do something with it? If CPU load of this VM is not high, maybe I can reduce numbers of CPU on it

Comment: Please don't add screenshots of terminal text. Instead copy/paste the text into the question and format it properly.